# Joomla FTP problem!

Tags: ftp, joomla

Good evening everyone, I been workin' on Ubuntu server, and I work from a remote pc that uses Windows XP Pro and ubuntu 9.10 too...ok the thing is...I installed joomla 1.5 last version on the ubuntu server from my pc and everything was good until I had to fill the ftp information, never found the connection path so I installed without it...now I have my joomla but I want to install some extensions and here's the problem, with the FTP Filezilla runin' on windows I connect perfectly with the server as with SSH in Ubuntu, but when I try to fill the FTP information on joomla, it doesnt recognizes the path, any idea about it?...

Answer (score 0):

If it's 1.5, you really don't need the FTP in the Joomla configuration set.

Try this: disable FTP in Joomla. (Global Configuration / Server)

Then try to install a component / module / plugin / whatever.

It's a bit counterintuitive, but will most likely work - or at least it does in my experience.  Joomla's file system can manage files for you... it's that whole content management system thing.

If you're dead set on enabling FTP, then check the Global Configuration, and see what the :Path to Temp-folder: is set to.  In 1and1's case, it'll be something like:

/homepages/26/d264424517/htdocs/english/tmp

Strip the 'tmp' and you'll see where '/english' would be the root path for the FTP setting, but again you most likely don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [FTP Layer hints](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=286792) on the Joomla! forum.  The info here had helped me resolved similar problems in the past.